# Diving into ASP.NET Web API Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I've been getting into the (relatively) new Web API that shipped with VS 2012 / MVC 4 / .NET 4.5, and have a custom message handler that handles authentication up and running. I also managed to hook it up to an old .NET 2.0 Membership Provider which was great.

I am now tackling the "authenticate with every HTTP request" issue by using a token in the HTTP request header, which I am comfortable with doing.

Now, for mobile apps when a user opens the app I show a login screen the first time, and don't show it again unless for any reason I get the "Unauthorized" message back. But for my web browser based projects I log in once and the browser (as long as it remains open) will remain authenticated.

What's the best way of forcing a time-out with this sort of authentication? I would prefer to log out based on inactivity, if anyone has done this. This one has me a bit stumped, so any guidance is appreciated :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two idle timeouts you need to consider.

1. Server Side idle timeout which expires to token you referred to
2. Client Side (mobile app) idle timeout which directs the user to re-enter credentials

**For #1**, You'd have to keep track of which tokens are active, or when they expire, etc... there are multiple ways to do this.  How I'd recommend you implement it depends on if your deploying to IIS or Azure and if you'll be scaling out.  In general though you want a central location where this information is stored.  A DB works, but is relatively slow. Session State could work in Azure as the Session State can be shared across servers via App Fabric, but in IIS, you'd have to use an additinal component to share session state across the servers.  Same holds true if you use the HttpRuntimeCache in .NET

*It should also be noted that doing such checking server-side is critical so as to prevent someone from hijacking the token you refer to depending on how you ultimately decide to implement things.*

**For #2**,  What we did in our iOS app was keep track of the idle timeout.  Each time user give input of any kind (e.g. BeginTouch event) in the app, we stop our idle timer and restart it.  The timer is configure to take the user to the login screen should the timer fire.  This same sort of thing should work well in Android, WP7, etc.